# Smart way to add parameters' signature with Square's Retrofit

Tags: retrofit

`I need to contact an API which requires that every request contain the signature of all parameters and url + nonce.

Example:

```
@GET("/users/{type}")
public void getUsers(
    @Path("type") String type,
    @Query("sort") boolean sort)
```

I should add a `X-Signature` header with contains `signature(nonce+"/users/"+type+"sort="+sort)`.
I thought I could do this with a `RequestInterceptor`'s `addHeader(String name, String value)` but I can`t as the signature varies for every request.

Is there a smart way to do this with Retrofit or will I just have to manually sign every request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I right in thinking that your signature is generated from [nonce]+[path]+[query params]

You could look at implementing a custom client and passing this into your `RestAdapter.Builder().setClient(new CustomClient)` method.

Something like `CustomClient extends OkClient` and then override the `execute(Request)` method. You will need to create a new Request object and pass that to `super.execute(updatedRequest)`.

```
@Override
public Response execute(Request request) throws IOException {
    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();

    // do work here to parse the request.getUrl() and extract path/params and generate the signature

    headers.addAll(request.getHeaders());
    headers.add(new Header("X-Signature", "signature"));
    Request updated = new Request(request.getMethod(), request.getUrl(), headers, request.getBody());
    return super.execute(updated);
}
```

If however there is no consistency to the generation of the signature then you will need to create the signature manually and add a @Header value in your call to your client.